# discord.js "messageDelete" listener returns a msg with undefined content

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that logs deleted messages within the server. (the messages won't be stored outside of the server). but when I try to use the "messageDelete" listener it returns and undefined content.

```py
client.on("messageDelete", async msg => {
    console.log(msg.content) //undefined
})
```

Is there a way I can get the content of the deleted message?
I'm on discord.js 12.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work if the message is cached.

When the delete event is called, it will point to the existing message object if it exists or create a new one but with only very basic info, like the id, etc...

That means the message needs to have been sent when the bot is up. The existing message will be referenced and the bot will be able to know what was said. If you restart the bot the cache is reset and the contents as well.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this snap of code to keep track on deleted messages, works fine even though it is really simple way of executing this.

```
bot.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) => {
const channel = bot.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'YOUR-LOG-CHANNEL-NAME-HERE')
channel.send(`Message from ${messageDelete.author.tag}: "${messageDelete.content}"  was deleted at ${messageDelete.channel}.`)});
```